# Need some help about computer programming.

Tags: soft-question

In mathematics, sometimes we have to do very long and time consuming work related to some functions or algorithm or some other work. For example if we want to check that for which last number $n$, $0$ Comes in the expansion of $3^n$ For another example, take partition function. If we want to find some relation we have to apply that practically on numbers. It takes very much time and energy. I have heard that we can setup a programme in computer to do this work.  Can anyone help me about this? I am in 9th grade.

Comment: The question seems a bit broad. What you seem to be asking is basically "is it true that we can use programs to solve tedious math problems?". Of course you can - for instance, you can use a calculator to do $43436646\times 65486690$. What exactly do you want to know?

Comment: _Mathematica_ is very good, though it might take a little time to get to grips with it. They also have a good stack exchange site.

Comment: You only need to know basic input/output, loops, mathematical functions,operators conditions,recursions(optional) and randomize functions. Just hold onto a programming language and Google.

Comment: Be aware that making computer do your long and time-consuming work might be a long and time-consuming task in itself.

Comment: If your interest is math only, then I would recommend _Mathematica_. On the other hand, if you would like to learn programming in general, you can find two nice introductions [here](http://tryruby.org/) and [here](http://learnyouahaskell.com/) (actually Python might be more useful because of its extensive library collection, but I'm not aware of any tutorials of similar or higher quality than these).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you consider spending money, I would suggest Wolfram's Mathematica. It can do pretty much everything related to maths in just a few lines of input. Almost no programming skills required.

Otherwise, using Python or Java is possible too, but you have to learn the language first and write more code for the same results. Yet I'm sure it won't take you too long, since using either on a "mathematical" level is pretty much straightforward.

You just have to download an [developing environment](https://netbeans.org/) and you're ready to go.
Additionally, you can find lots of code samples for mathematical functions on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

You could easily do that.
In order to do that you have to first learn a programming language.
I recommend Python for starting. It's an easy language which is widely used among scientists.